# How to calculate geometric mean from dataframe in python

Tags: python

do you guys have experience with calculation of yearly geometric mean (of variable 'Change' for every year separately) from daily data? For better imagination i am attaching used dataset.
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBkw9.jpg)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.